# How do you check if music is playing by using a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, audio-player, background-music, android-music-player

I would like to prevent some of my code from executing *only* when music or videos are currently playing. How would I accomplish this using a broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You don't need a broadcast receiver for this - `AudioManager` is your friend:

`AudioManager.isMusicActive()` does the job you want, have a closer look here for details: [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive%28%29)

here is an example:

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(manager.isMusicActive())
 {
     // do something - or do it not
 }
```

Comment: Hi Martin,

Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your code but it states that "getSystemService is undefined for the type" <class name>.

I need to place your code in the broadcast receiver because that's were I need to prevent certain code from executing.

Truly,
Emad

Comment: Hi Martin, I found out why the error was occurring. I needed to add the keyword: context before getSystemService and it worked. Truly, Emad

Comment: Is there a way to detect the details of the music too? Song-name; artist etc?

Comment: This method starts the service if music is active. Can someone tell me how to start service when music player is opened?

Comment: I don't know why but in my case _manager.isMusicActive()_ is always true even if there is not active music player.