# Is device playing something?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Is there a way to know if the telephone is playing anything? for example a ringtone.

My phone doesn't work properly and I sometimes get a call without a ringtone. I mean, I can see the incoming call screen but nothing is heard (of course it is not in silence). It happens sometimes.

So I programmed something to detect incoming calls (a receiver) and play the default ringtone. It works pretty well when my phone fails, because I force it by playing it again.

The problem comes when my phone works! because in that case you can hear both at the same time (phone's and mine) and sounds terrible!

So I need to do one thing of these two:

-Either detect that the phone worked well (it is ringing) so I don't have to play anything.
-Or stop any current ringing (if any) and play it myself always.

Any help?

P.S.: I tried isMusicActive() and it doesn't work for the ringing.

Comment: Similar question, possible dupe: [How do you check if music is playing from a broadcast receiver?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7323915/404469). It utilizes the `AudioManager.isMusicActive()` method just as the current answers point out.

Comment: Ah, now that you explained the context, I think you may want to search http://android.stackexchange.com/ and post a question there. Not as a developer, but as a user.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [isMusicActive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive%28%29) method in [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html). I'm quite sure that it'll work system wide, but if you try it and it doesn't, do post back here.

Comment: Pretty sure then that what you want isn't possible via the SDK.

Comment: `AudioManager.isMusicActive()` always return **true** on device model **Meizu MX2** even when music is not playing. has anyone encounter this issue ?

Comment: What if the audio being played is a caller? Is that still considered music?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) gives a great description of how to manage audio focus.
You could implement `onAudioFocusedChangedListener` to get constant updates on what is playing.

And even the `isMusicActive()` method may also be helpful, as @raghav points out.