# How can I use robotium to test if audio is being played at the native level?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gstreamer, robotium, opensl

Or is this even possible? I am not using MediaPlayer or any java level component, but rather using the GStreamer framework, which operates through OpenSL at the native layer.

I am guessing that I have to use the NDK to hook into the audio engine somehow. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323915/how-do-you-check-if-music-is-playing-by-using-a-broadcast-receiver

Comment: Answered via Maszter
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323915/how-do-you-check-if-music-is-playing-by-using-a-broadcast-receiver