# Programmatically check which Music player is playing now

Tags: android, android-music-player

Is there a way we can check **programmatically** **Which Music player is playing right now**?

like **Google Play**, **Samsung default Music Player**, any **3rd party music player**

Actually, we need to programmatically handle **play/pause of music player**. Google Play and Samsung Music works differently with code :

```
// Google Play do not play pause with this code
// it is using different package name i guess
CmdStop = "togglepause";
i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand.togglepause");
i.putExtra(CmdName, CmdStop);
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Any help is appriciated

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

you don't need a broadcast receiver for this - `AudioManager` is your friend:

AudioManager.isMusicActive() does the job you want, have a closer look here for details: [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive%28%29)

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(manager.isMusicActive())
 {
     // do something - or do it not
 }
```

[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323915/how-do-you-check-if-music-is-playing-by-using-a-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: This will give whether music is running or not.. I need to check which player is playing songs now?

Comment: @Kushal the code above and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#dispatchMediaKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent) should allow you to handle play/pause without needing to know which player is running.

Comment: @Kanaiya please add answer  how to check audio status like play, pause or stop.