# How to start a service when another app gets active?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to start my app/service when another app get's active or music is played from that app. Is this possible with Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are specifically looking for starting your service when music player starts, take a look at AndroidManager API. You can register for callbacks using 
[registerAudioPlaybackCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#registerAudioPlaybackCallback(android.media.AudioManager.AudioPlaybackCallback,%20android.os.Handler))

Also there is method from same AudioManager which tells you if Music isActive
[isActive - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7324006/6157920)

[isMusicActive](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive())